# How to move member to channel | discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

How to move member to a different channel without `member: discord.Member, channel : discord.VoiceChannel` arguments in a function if i have variables with channel id and member id in this function?

```
@commands.command()
async def msg(ctx):
    member = 848494088563327006
    channel = 430388650786947083
    await member.move_to(channel)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use `get_member`, to get a member object by ID [docs for get_member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get%20member#discord.Guild.get_member) and `get_channel` to get the channel object by ID [docs for get_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_channel#discord.Guild.get_channel). Then do the `move_to` command

I am not an expert with this but this would be an idea.